# Paladin High Elf

Tags: dnd-5e, paladin

I am about to start a campaign with a group of friends, we're all new to Dnd so I'm curious how it'll go! Without my knowledge I wanted to be a high elf Paladin. Little did I know that when I did a bit of research on the internet, that the class and race combination is not very good. That didn't scare me away though, because I am looking forward to being a non stereotype character.

What I'm asking though, what would be a nice background for my character? I already chose noble as a standard background, but I would like to add a bit of my own ideas. One of those things would be, how come a high elf noble became a paladin.

I had a few ideas myself: her boyfriend was a paladin and he died in battle, she wanted to honor him by picking up his sword and armor and fight in his place.
Or: She saw a paladin saving her family from whatever reason, and she wanted to thank the paladin by returning the favor in doing good deeds herself.

But I'd love to have a paladin that's not a stereotype, and that's why I'm asking, what was your paladin like? I might get some inspiration from it.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Please take our [tour](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn more about the types of questions that work well here. Yours is currently very opinion-based may be better served on a [forum](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5449/ive-been-told-my-question-is-better-suited-to-a-forum-but-where-should-i-go).

Comment: Hi, and welcome! Unfortunately this site isn't a typical discussion forum and we only handle questions that can have “best” or “correct” answers (because forums do that badly, this site was created to do it well). As a consequence, it doesn't handle questions like this one, where the asker just wants ideas and thoughts. For that, discussion forums can't be beat though, and we have [a list of RPG discussion forums](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5449) that we have compiled. Take a look at that list and choose one to post this question to. It's a good question, just not for *here*; sorry!

Comment: Alright, my apologies! And thank you for the warning.

Comment: @Lucy No apologies necessary! This is a great site for certain types of questions :) If you do earn enough rep, coming into [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11/rpg-general-chat) may also be useful :)

Comment: @Lucy, while you're here, I encourage you to look around. It's not a discussion forum, but it's a great place for answers. I dipped in here last year and was so impressed by the way the site comports itself and interacts with respect and maturity, that it's become a daily visit.